# Flow does not understand the code correctly if Component is a third-party module typed via flow-typed

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, conditional-rendering

**UPDATE: 2018-05-23**

So, the reason why this can not be reproduces is, that i removed some parts of the code (project-related stuff) that where actually part of the problem.

1) I use react-router (react-router-dom) in this project and added some flow-compatibility by adding a lib ([lib] section inside of `.flowconfig`) where i make third-party module definitions.

The file four react-router:

```
declare module 'react-router-dom' {
    declare module.exports: any;
}
```

2) The conditional Rendering included a Component from React-Router:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

// ....

{this.state.something !== null &&
<li>
    <Link to={`/to/${this.state.something.id}`}>
        {this.state.something.name}
    </Link>
</li>
}

// ....
```

So flow stops working correctly in such a scenario.

It is NOT caused by the string template usage and it is NEITHER caused by the usage as attribute, it is connected to the "flowtype-mock-module".

Changing the flow-typed definitions [to this](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x/flow_v0.63.x-/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js) does not help. Still the same problem

---

working with flowtype and react i face the following problem quiet oftenly. How would you solve it or are there any best practices to handle the following scenario?

A type definition for react state:

```
type SomeType = {
    id: number,
};

type State = {
    something: SomeType | null,
}
```

and a conditional rendering scenario:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.something !== null &&
                <b>this.state.something.id</b>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now flow would tell me, that i can not access the id property of null but "something" can actually never be null, so it would have to be of type SomeType.

running flow will result in something like:

```
Cannot get this.state.something.id because property id is missing in null [1].

 [1] 17│     something: SomeType | null,
       :
     60│                         </div>
     61│                         {this.state.something !== null &&
     62│                         <b>
     63│                             {this.state.something.id}
     66│                         </b>
```

Comment: Flow maybe assume that because you try to call .id property that this is an object which cannot be null rather than undefined or empty {}. So this check will always be true

Comment: Your example seems to work fine in latest version : https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAZVyQBVraBeOAb1LjmABMAXHAB2AVxAAjJFFIBfclRr0YKGOy484AZ0YwAFsBEBzYQxDNWcAD6ixAG3vzyaeym3a4AWUoBhXJAiSCLwSAAe6iL8nsjoMAB0-uAQQSEAPJxyADQqakgAfJq8RFEyABQAlEW8cEQwYlAicGVaNXBp-MAAbvmtbVwGwNrx2qrqI3qGJnAAhGwc4o5wAGTL7ZL5g8OjeRMWgybxAmkA9BsK-e0nnT19FVoKCkA

Comment: Could you try the latest version of Flow or make an example that throws an error?

Comment: Thank you James, updating flow-bin (0.68 => 0.72) solved the issue!

Comment: Ah, sorry, not true - same problem on 0.72

Comment: Try grabbing the value of `something` out of the state before running the checks. Like: `const {something} = this.state; ... {something != null && (conditional elements)}`. That usually does the trick.

Comment: Then this is a bug in flowtype, i reported an [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6345). I dont want to adopt my coding any more than i have already done.